# can not bind to [(ngModel)] since it is not a known property of input

Tags: angular

I am trying to use my-date-picker in my angular application. It was working perfectly till the time everything was in app.component.html but then I break everything into modules and I start getting this error in users.component.html
[image]

I was thinking that might be something is wrong with date-picker component but I can not even able to use [(ngModel)]

I have already form module imported in my app module and after getting this error I have imported form module in each module but still can not get rid of this error till now.

my folder structure is like this
[image]

my relative code

```js
//app.module.ts

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {FlexLayoutModule} from "@angular/flex-layout";
import { MyDatePickerModule } from "mydatepicker";
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material';
import { RoutingModule } from './routing/routing.module';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RoutingModule,
    RouterModule,
    SharedModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    MyDatePickerModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCheckboxModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}


//dashboard.module.ts
import { SharedModule } from './../shared/shared.module';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { UsersComponent } from './users/users.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MaterialModule } from '../material/material.module';
import { MyDatePickerModule } from 'mydatepicker';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    SharedModule,
    MyDatePickerModule
  ],
  declarations: [UsersComponent]
})
export class DashboardModule {}
```

Comment: Import FormsModule and MatCheckboxModule in RoutingModule or move UsersComponent to AppModule

Comment: Set name attribute for all inputs like <input type='text' name='name' [(ngModel)]='name' />

Comment: @yurzui, thanks, it worked. I have imported  FlexLayoutModule,
    MyDatePickerModule, FormsModule in the routing module and it starts getting worked as it was working when everything was in app.component.html but I made this module just specific for routing so if I use any third party library in the future, I have to import it into RoutingModule?